# Set containing all boundary point must be closed set

Tags: calculus

Given a set C, if C contains all boundary points, must C be a closed set?

Sorry if there is any repeated question, but I wish to look for an answer with very basic knowledge. I only know few knowledge about this question.

1. A boundary point of a set C is the point such that every open disk centered at the point contains points in C and also points not in C.
2. A open set is a set C that for every point $s$ in C, there exist an open disk so that the disk is in C.
3. A set is closed if its complement is open.

I found some reference about exterior but I also not able to proof exterior is open with these knowledge.

Comment: Since you ask about open disks, do you have in mind that all your sets are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, or of an arbitrary metric space, or of a general topological space?

Comment: No, the natural numbers, viewed as a subset of Euclidean space, is not closed and has no boundary (hence contains all boundary points).

Comment: @mcd actually our lecture is teaching this based on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but when I approach to lecturer, he mentioned try no not mention the distance so the conclusion can be as general as well.

Comment: @AndrewZhang I think natural numbers is closed. Because its complement, $\cdots \cup (-1,0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1,2) \cup \cdots $ is actually open.

Comment: A theorem: "A set is closed if and only if it contains its boundary " so what you are saying is true

Comment: @Zima yes I am trying to proof the both definition agrees. Hence I try not mentioning this theorem and struggling on these theorems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $C$ is not a closed set, then there exists a limit point $p$ of $C$ such that $p \not \in C$. By the definition of a limit point, in every open disk $N_r(p)$ centered at $p$ (or "neighborhood" of $p$), there exists a point $q$ different from $p$ satisfying $q \in N_r(p)$ and $q \in C$. Then, $p$ must be a boundary point of $C$ since every neighborhood of $p$ contains $p$ itself, a point that is not in $C$ by assumption, and $q$, a point that is in $C$. This is a contradiction that all boundary points of $C$ are in $C$. Hence, $C$ must be a closed set. QED

As an extension, you can also prove that any closed set must contain all its boundary points. Again, we prove this by contradiction. Suppose that $p$ is a boundary point of $C$ not in $C$. Then, every neighborhood of $p$ must contain at least one point not in $C$ and at least one point $q$ in $C$ such that $q \neq p$ (since $p \not \in C$). Hence, we can deduce that $p$ is a limit point of $C$, which has to be contained in $C$ by the definition of a closed set, in contradiction to the assumption that $p \not \in C$. Therefore, we can conclude that a closed set must contain all its boundary points. QED

Overall, this can be summarized with the statement:

> A set $C$ is closed if and only if it contains all of its boundary points.

Hope it helps.

Comment: May I ask further? If I know $p \notin C$ and for every open disk $N_r(p)$ centered at $p$ exist $q$ is in the disk so that $q \in C$, is it enough to conclude $p$ is a boundary point?

Comment: @Learner Yes. Because in this case $p$ contained in each of those disks would be the point not contained in $C$ and $q$ would always be the point that is in both the disk and $C$, so this is enough to conclude that $p$ is a boundary point.

Comment: And unlike the definition of limit points which has restrictions on the point having to be different from the center, the point in the open disk that is not in $C$ can be the center of the disk, so in this case, $p$ is a boundary point.

Comment: ok thank you very much!